# Дублирование вставки данных

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Работаю над созданием форума. Возникла следующая проблема, при добавлении новых сообщений. Во время обновления страницы данные вторично (многократно) вставляются на форум, хотя я очищаю POST переменные. Как эту проблему решить? (В остальном код работает отлично). Привожу кусок кода отвечающий за вставку данных сообщения на форум.

```
  $NameUser = $_POST['NameUser'];
  $NewMSG = $_POST['NewMSG'];

  if (isset($_POST['NameUser']) && isset($_POST['NewMSG']) && ($_POST['NameUser']<>'') && ($_POST['NewMSG'] <> ''))
  {
     //echo $NameUser;
     //echo $NewMSG;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO forum_msg (code_forum, msg_text, msg_author)
              VALUES (".$forum.",'".$NewMSG."','".$NameUser."');";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     unset($_POST['NewMSG']);
     unset($_POST['NameUser']);
  }
```

Comment: Очищение не поможет, так как данные при обновлении страницы перепосылаются. Не знаю, насколько правильно, но есть вариант редиректа, когда по успешной вставке идет перенаправление на другую страницу.

Comment: а поподробнее про вариант редиректа можно?)

Comment: ну сколько можно?.. [SQL injection](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Answer (score 4):

В форму вставляете `hidden` поле с уникальным ID, при отправке формы вы проверяете есть ли в `$_SESSION['form']` такой идентификатор, если нет то добавляем его туда и пишем данные в БД, если уже есть, то ничего не делаем.

Проще простого.

Comment: не получается...(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после добавления данных перенаправить человека на другую страницу к примеру которая сообщит, что пост добавлен или переведите человека на страницу с его постом через `header("lacation: страница")`, тогда `$_POST` потеряется и вам не надо будет выдумывать как проверять сессию. Дело в том, что сессия по умолчанию открывается при открытии браузера и закрывается при его закрытии. Потому сколько бы вы скрытое поле сессия не добавляли она будет одна и та же и вы будете добавлять данные до бесконечности. Ну это в вашем варианте, хотя можно точно как сказали выше про создание параметра в сессии и если он присутствует, то тогда не сохранять сессию. А когда выводите форму убивать в сессии этот параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не получается, не работает, такой же дублеж полей... c сессиями ни разу не работал. делаю вот так:

```
  $NameUser = $_POST['NameUser'];
  $NewMSG = $_POST['NewMSG'];
  if ($_SESSION['form']<>$_POST['SessionID'])
  {
    $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST['SessionID'];
    if (isset($_POST['NameUser']) && isset($_POST['NewMSG']) && ($_POST['NameUser']<>'') && ($_POST['NewMSG'] <> ''))
    {
     //echo $NameUser;
     //echo $NewMSG;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO forum_msg (code_forum, msg_text, msg_author)
              VALUES (".$forum.",'".$NewMSG."','".$NameUser."');";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     unset($_POST['NewMSG']);
     unset($_POST['NameUser']);
    }  
  }
```

а в форме прописал скрытное поле с названием SessionID, Что не так делаю?